# QGIS server (WMS) how serve raster constructed on the fly from multiple tiles with expression

Tags: qgis, raster, wms, server

I’m not sure how to precisely describe the functionality but I have been looking around and I didn't find an answer.
Basically I have a large number of small raster files - say 1000 served by WMS server (QGIS).
These raster layers do overlap and some don’t.
User can dynamically request to select any of these layers. Say 100 out of the 1000. This is a variable input so can not be pre-established.

From user selection I need to construct a single virtual layer which combines all the individual raster layers selected by the user.

This virtual layer would ideally be computed by the WMS server and streamed to the user so less computation done on the client side.

The layer would be computed using an expression such as A+B or A>B?A:B at pixel level.

Is WMS server suited for such application?